# PayPal Subscription create_order_error / 400 VALIDATION_ERROR response

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I've implemented the following code to accept subscriptions with PayPal's smart buttons. It was working correctly, but it has been showing an error message for the last couple of hours. No changes have been made to the code.

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': plan_id
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        //alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The error message in the browser console is:

```
A boolean is being passed as a fourth parameter to window.open. This is not used and may cause an exception in a future release.
POST https://www.paypal.com/smart/api/billagmt/subscriptions/I-XXXXXXXXXXXX/cartid 400
create_order_error
```

Is anyone having the same issue?

Comment: The warning about a boolean being passed is something you can ignore. You need to post full details about the capture error response that returns the 400.  Obtain it from the Network tab if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 validation error that looks like a PayPal issue, I think it will be rolled back. Try again in something like 4 hours or so and see if it's resolved.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. It was a PayPal issue! How can they do that when there are so many online stores that depend on them.

Comment: @gab06 they just do. I wold recommend staying away from them if you are doing recurring subscriptions.

Comment: This issue was resolved fairly quickly ¯\ (ツ) /¯